# In python, how do i search a word within a string, ignoring capitals and punctuation, but not words that include the key word?

Tags: python, string, search, filter, keyword

```
#initialize list of indexes
index_list=[]

for i in range(len(doc_list)):
    doc_list_lower=doc_list[i].lower()
    doc_list_lower.replace(',','')
    doc_list_lower.replace('.','')
    print(doc_list_lower)

for i in range(len(doc_list)):
    
    #lower all words in doc_list at index
    doc_list_lower=doc_list[i].lower()
    
    #remove commas and periods from doc_list
    doc_list_lower.replace(',','')
    doc_list_lower.replace('.','')
    
    #create list of all words in doc_list item
    doc_words=doc_list_lower.split()
         
    #check if word is in document
    if keyword in doc_words and not(len(keyword)<len(doc_words((doc_words.index(keyword))))):
        index_list.append(i)

#return list
print(index_list)
```

trying to search a word within a list of strings. I have to identify the all the items in the list where the word is found.

Comment: This will probably be a regrex function, can you provide an example input and an expected output?

Comment: You should read about https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html.

Comment: Could you provide an example of such a string with a keyword? Also the code snippet seems to include functionality that is irrelevant to the question if I am not mistaken